# How do I share a post in the Facebook app for iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications, facebook

My mom uses the Facebook app for iPad and wanted to share a post, such as on the web interface:

[image: FB Share]

How does one share a post within the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version (5.2.2) of the Facebook app has added support for the share button.

> New Share link to re-post stories from your news feed

Answer (score 6):

You cannot re-share posts from the iOS Facebook app.

You can re-share posts if you:

- Browser to https://www.facebook.com/ in mobile Safari
- Log in
- Click the three bar icon in the upper left hand corner to bring up the side bar
- Scroll to the very bottom of the side bar
- Click the "Desktop Version" link at the very bottom of the side

This will give you the full Facebook desktop web view and from here you can re-share posts in your timeline.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the Facebook for iPad app does not allow this in the native app.

One way to do this on the iPad is to log into Facebook from Safari and share a post as you would from any web browser.

Another possibility is the [**Friendly Plus for Facebook**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/friendly-plus-for-facebook/id382011064?mt=8) app. I'm not sure if it allows sharing of posts, but it does say in the release notes for version 3.5.3 that it "fixed share issue" so it's a possibility. Worth $.99 I'd say.

Comment: I would like some verification on the app you mention. If anyone has used it, please let me know if this works!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't own an iPad (yet) or I'd try it out myself.

Answer (score -1):

Google post to facebook marklet- its a copy of the web page post to facebook JavaScript. Keep as bookmark, activate in browser when on page you'd like to post. Pop ups cannot be blocked tho. A new tab will pop up with the familiar posting window (provided u r loogged in tuo fb or have nactive cookies!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Naxalite971! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.